# How to free memory after deleting an object

Tags: r, memory

I am contacting you directly as I am unable to find the solution by myself. I am loading huge `shapePoly` using the `readShapePoly` function. I do some treatments on them and substraction in order to work on substractions rather than the whole `ShapePolyDataFrame`. 
My trouble is that I am unable to free memory on R.

For example, let say I have open a `Shapepoly`:

```
tmp <- readShapePoly("C:/…/clc06_c112.shp", verbose=TRUE, repair=FALSE)
```

then I try to erase the variable `tmp` :
    gc()

```
           *used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used (Mb)
Ncells  5314951 142.0   15726413 420.0  19658017  525
Vcells 26412646 201.6  101851119 777.1 117429418  896*


rm(tmp)
gc()
         used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used (Mb)
Ncells 482945 12.9   12581130 336.0  19658017  525
Vcells 588952  4.5   81480895 621.7 117429418  896
```

Despite it seems to have effect on R, it doesn’t have effect on the memory when tracking it in the windows system. I think the variable `tmp` might be a pointer but I am unable to solve it.

Comment: Might be that the OS does not reclaim the memory as long as it does not need it, even though R has released it already.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Good point.  I know in OS X the memory table lists categories "wired, in use, available, free" (names not exactly correct).  Is there a similar categorization in Windows?

Comment: In Windows 7, you can see them in the Resources Monitor if you have admin rights.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to release the memory in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561331/how-to-release-the-memory-in-r)