# xlsx::loadWorkbook error in R

Tags: r, memory-management, xlsx, rjava, xlconnect

I have a moderate size `.xlsx` file with the dimension of 40,000 rows and 15 columns. I loaded that data into R Workspace by using `xlsx::loadWorkbook` function. Before loading that data, my PC `RAM` size is `90 MB`. After loading that data, my PC `RAM` size is `650 MB`. Below is the code which I used to load the data.

```
library(xlsx)
file=\\file_path\\
wb <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(file)
```

Then I removed `wb` object from the R Workspace by using `rm(wb)`. After I removed that file from Workspace, my PC `RAM` size din't change. It's still remains same as `650MB`. I am very sure that, I don't have any other objects in my Workspace. Why it is happening? and What should I do to free up my PC `RAM` size?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this thread about memory management: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561331/release-memory-in-r

Comment: For a more memory efficient way of importing data, you could export the data to csv first. This is much quicker and less RAM hungry.

Comment: My objective is to add colors to the cells based on their numbers. That's why I am loading them in workbook format.

Answer (score 0):

I did some exploring on my own. You might want to try the following

```
memory.size()
gc()
memory.size()
rm(list=ls())
memory.size()
gc()
memory.size()
```

The function `memory.size()` reports the amount of memory currently in use. The function `gc()`causes a garbage collection to take place. After which, you can use `memory.size()` again to see how much memory has been freed up from garbage collection. The command `rm(list=ls())` removes all objects from your global environment. After which, you can use `memory.size()` to see how much memory has been freed after removing all objects in your global environment.

At this point, there might be some more memory still in use, even though you have removed all objects from the global environment (which you have described). Do another garbage collection and check the memory. Your memory should have gone down (which was what I found). Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see significant improvement with the above functions. It just reduced single digit(`9 MB`) space.